# Video not filling the screen in XBMC

Tags: video, kodi, aspect-ratio

I have XBMC running on a win 7 machine and I can't get it to totally fill the screen. There is always, on all media files, black bars on all four sides.

any idea what I can try?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but I stumbled across this and in case no-one else can research shortcuts (from [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Keyboard)):

on your keyboard (PC),  <kbd>Z</kbd> Zooms/sets aspect ratio

or while watching a movie click the Video Reel icon and click view until you find what you want

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have the device set to "center" images and keep aspect ratio. You probably want to look into setting it to "stretch/zoom" to fill screen.

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Aspect_Ratio

Options are:

> KEEP Aspect ratio will be kept, and the image will be scaled down or
>   up so that it fits inside the box, with transparent bars either side
>   if the ratios are not the same.
>
> STRETCH   Aspect ratio is not kept - the image will be stretched so
>   that it exactly fits the box.
>
> SCALE     Aspect ratio is kept, and the image is scaled up so that it
>   fills the box, with any portions that lie outside the box being
>   cropped off.
>
> CENTER    Aspect ratio is kept, and the image is left unscaled, centered
>   within the box. It may be cropped if the image is larger than the box,
>   or may have a transparent border if the image is smaller than the box.

Comment: where do I change this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using composite video for connecting the TV, you could try component video (or HDMI).

I have an an older plasma 720 but it doesnt have an HDMI input. I kept trying to use the yellow-red-white cable (composite video + audio) with no success... Fortunately my tv does have 2 component inputs (the one with 5 ends) which is red-blue-green (for video) and white and red (for audio)... I bought a HDMI to component video adapter and all issues were gone.